# Unable to clear interval or timeout when changing orientation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, settimeout, setinterval

I have an image carousel built with SwipeJS, that I destroy and then rebuild when changing orientation from portrait -> landscape or landscape -> portrait.

I have an issue where I can't seem to clear the interval/timeout with my code below. As I can see that the `console.log(now)` starts by being called every 5 secs (as expected) to being called every 2.5 secs. Presumably this is because the initial `setInterval` function is still active.

How can I clear/kill that so that there is only one interval working at any one time?

I am using jQuery Mobile 1.3.1.

```
if ($.event.special.orientationchange.orientation() === 'portrait') {
    // Portrait mode

    clearTimeout(slideshowHandle);

    // ...trash the old slider, then build a new one...
} else {
    // Landscape mode

    clearTimeout(slideshowHandle);

    // ...trash the old slider, then build a new one...
}

// call the SwipeJS next method every 5 seconds to move to the next slide in the carousel
var slideshowHandle = setInterval(function() {

  // just some code for debugging purposes
  var now = new Date(),
  now = now.getHours()+':'+now.getMinutes()+':'+now.getSeconds();
  console.log(now);

  // trigger a swipe 'next'
  container.Swipe('next');

}, 5000);
```

Comment: listen to `orientationchange` event. `$(document).on("orientationchange", function (e) { if(e.orientation = "portrait") { //code } });`

Comment: @Omar The orientation change-detection code works fine, I have other things going on like showing landscape-specific content and that all works fine. I think the problem is more my `setInterval` implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must have had a scoping issue as attaching it to `window` done the trick (and also changing back to `clearInterval`):

```
// clear the interval on the slideshow 'next' (if we have it) when changing orientation
if (window.slideshowHandle) {
   window.clearInterval(window.slideshowHandle);
}

// call the SwipeJS next method every 5 seconds to move to the next slide in the carousel
window.slideshowHandle = window.setInterval(function() {
   swipeContainer.Swipe('next');
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Hah, nice. We could not see that without the whole code base, but I'm glad that you found the answer with my help and by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `clearInterval(slideshowHandle)` instead of `clearTimout`

Check this for reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearInterval

Comment: Thanks, but I was initially using `clearInterval` but changed it to `clearTimeout` as it was not working. I've reverted to `clearInterval` and can confirm i'm still seeing the same problem.